# Not show the calling app in the list of options in external intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I am raising an external intent to open a file type. My requirement is that I don't want to show my own application in the list of supported applications which can open the file in this case. However, I do want my app to be able to open this file type when other apps try to open such files.

Comment: Why would you not include your own app if it can handle the intent?

Comment: I am giving user an option to open the file from my app or any third party. if the user choses other apps, then i show the option to open it in other apps. I dont want to show my app option in the second option